# Junit com spring Autowired

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, services, http-request

Estou com um grande problema que no meu GenericService eu utilizo um @Autowired em um HttpServletRequest (Mesmo não conhecendo a utilidade, pois, não conheço tão bem a arquitetura), e precisava utilizar teste unitário para bateria de teste em meus services, porém, quando vou injetar o bean no meu teste o spring nao consegue injetar esse HttpServletRequest como ele conseguia antes no container.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'br.com.field.service.TalhaoService':
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire
field: private javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
br.com.visioncore.service.GenericServiceImpl.httpRequest; nested exception
is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
qualifying bean of type [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] found for
dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Alguém sabe como faria para testar isso? Ja consegui pegar as minhas configurações de contexto dentro do Test e só me falta isso agora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Não há um erro de verdade

Este comportamento é completamente natural e esperado.

Motivo: uma requisição HTTP (ou a classe que encapsula tal requisição) só vai existir realmente no ambiente web provido por um *container* ou Servidor de Aplicação.

## Teste unitário e camadas web

Infelizmente não é muito fácil nem produtivo fazer testes unitários de implementações que tratam especificamente de requisições ou então da *view* do sistema, enfim, são componentes web e é complicado lidar com eles foram desse ambiente.

O ideal seria usar remover toda a lógica da aplicação e colocar em componentes de negócios e então focar os testes unitários nessas camadas.

## Teste de integração

As camadas de controladores e *views* podem ser testadas em um tipo de teste de um pouco mais alto nível, por exemplo, num teste de integração.

Você pode criar um testes unitário que inicialize o sistema num *container* "embutido" como Jetty ou Tomcat. Então use uma API *client* para fazer requisições HTTP e simular um usuário. Ou ainda pode usar o Selenium/WebDriver para realmente abrir o navegador e simular o uso do sistema. O [Spring Boot para web](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), que já adiciona dependências do Tomcat e permite a inicialização do sistema com uma linha de código, pode ajudar caso consiga adaptar seu projeto.

## Use *Mocks*

Outra possibilidade mais específica para seu caso é criar um *mock* do objeto ausente. Crie uma classe que implemente `HttpServletRequest` e retorne valores fixos para o seu teste. Depois, configure-a em um XML do Spring separadamente e inclua o XML somente na classe de teste que precisar dele.

O problema com isso é que *mocks* podem enganá-lo, isto é, o teste pode funcionar (já que você coloca valores fictícios) e numa situação real o navegador ou o cliente HTTP acaba enviando valores diferentes na requisição HTTP.

Minha recomendação é usar mocks somente onde houver alguma lógica importante que valha a pena ser testada e que possa ser validada realmente.

Comment: Valeu pela Aula, eu pra ter uma visão mais clara agora.